# change arabic font in babel latex + pdfLatex

Tags: fonts, pdftex, babel, arabic

how I make "\babelfont" works with PdfLatex compiler.
I know it works with xeLatex compiler.
or any method that I can change arabic font using babel and with PdfLaTex compiler.
I appreciate any help

Comment: Please add an example showing the way you use to write Arabic so that we can help you.

Comment: `babel` relies on `arabi`. See https://ctan.org/pkg/arabi. Choices are limited, and changing the font is not simple, but the `arabi` manual provides detailed instructions on how to install and configure your system.